How to do add_header and proxy_set_header different for every ingress
I'm trying porting my application on k8s, it's composed by many microservices, written in java and angular , I've developed it using docker-starter and used an nginx to route to different applications and different locations using different custom-headers potentially different from server and server, from location and location.
With ingress-nginx I tried a way to do add_header and proxy_set_header globally, I followed this useful guide, but in that way I can't accomplish my task.
What I need is to have headers "ingress based" and not globally set, could you give me some hint to implement this task?
More details about my environment:

rancher 2.8.0
rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-1.9.4-rancher1
k8s Provider: RKE1, Kubernetes Version: v1.27.12

Thanks
